# ¿Cómo cuento el número de vocales en una palabra?

Tags: c, string, funciones

El resultado que me da sin importar que escriba es que hay 10 vocales, como si fueran cierto todas las condiciones.
¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

¿Qué tendría que hacer si ahora quiero hacer una función que cuente las vocales?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int s=0,y;
    char ar[10];
    printf("Ingresa una palabra menor a 10 caracteres:\n");
    gets(ar);
    printf("La palabra que ingresaste fue:\n");
    puts(ar);
    for(y=0;y<10;y++)
    {

        if(ar[y]=='a'||ar[y]=='e'||ar[y]=='i'||ar[y]=='o'||ar[y]=='u'||ar[y]=='A'||ar[y]=='E'||ar[y]=='I'||ar[y]=='O'||ar[y]=='U');
           {
                s++;
           }

    }
    printf("Aparecen %d vocales\n",s);
    printf("la primera letra es %c.\n",ar[0]);
}
```

Comment: deberías comprobar las tildes también no ?

Comment: Cierto como dice Juan Manuel, debes quitar el ";" del IF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debes quitar el punto y coma al final de la instrucción `if` para que se ejecute condicionalmente el código que incrementa `s`.

Answer (score 1):

tu codigo esta asi:

```
> if(ar[y]=='a'||ar[y]=='e'||ar[y]=='i'||ar[y]=='o'||ar[y]=='u'||ar[y]=='A'||ar[y]=='E'||ar[y]=='I'||ar[y]=='O'||ar[y]=='U');
>            {
>                 s++;
>            }
```

deberias quitar el punto y coma asi:

```
> if(ar[y]=='a'||ar[y]=='e'||ar[y]=='i'||ar[y]=='o'||ar[y]=='u'||ar[y]=='A'||ar[y]=='E'||ar[y]=='I'||ar[y]=='O'||ar[y]=='U')
>            {
>                 s++;
>            }
```